# include modules for other modules

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have:

```
modules: News 
  action:
    executeIndex
    executeEdit
    etc.
  templates:
    _editPlus.php
    IndexSuccess.php
    EditSuccess.php

modules: EditNews
      action:
      ...
      templates:
       ...
```

In modules News all is good. I would like include executeEdit and EditSuccess for modules EditNews. I would like copy all functionality and template. 
How can i make it? **I dont want copy files.** I would like somethings like include_partial or renderTemplate ? Is possible?
I use Symfony 1.4.13

Comment: If both actions are identical, why do you need to have an additional action in the module EditNews?

Comment: i dont have repeat code and if in first i add changes then i would like auto change in second

Comment: If they should be and remain identical, why bother creating the second action at all? What's the problem with reusing a single action?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is:

```
return $this->renderPartial('partialname'); // renders you _partial.php
return $this->renderText('foobar'); // will only render you 'foobar'
```

and this might be also relevant for you:

```
return 'Finish'; // in your action will use ActionnameFinish.php as template
```

Comment: i would like render executeEdit and EditSucces for other execute and other Success. I dont want repeat code.

Answer (score 0):

You are illustrating why it is important to have lean actions and fat models. You should move most of your logic to your models or other external classes, especially if you are going to reuse that code in different actions. That way you should be able to reduce the amount of code in your actions to only a few lines, at it will be trivial to maintain a common codebase across different actions.

In the end it seems like you will be needing two seperate actions though, so either you do copy the code and go through the trouble of maintaining it in different places (=bad practice), or you refactor it like I suggested.

Comment: I would like use executeEdit and EditSuccess (module News) in executeEdit and EditSucces (module second)